# Git - push to remote repository failed

Tags: git, github, version-control

Ok, Im new to Git and I have isue that can't solve by myself, even after couple of hours spended here and there on reading topics with similar question. 
I will try to describe it in details:

name of my github repo is rep_1

In rep_1 there are 5 folders (1,2,...,5), and there is index.html in each. I made new folder 'work' and i `git clone <url>` my forked repo. In folder 1/index.html I used `git init` and `git add .` and `git commit -m` to make some changes.

Then I used `git remote add 1 https://github.com/username/rep1` after that,

`git push 1`

and I got:

> fatal: The current branch master has no upstream branch. To push the current 
>   branch and set the remote as upstream, use git push --set-upstream 1 master

I used that too but it didn't help. Got this time:

> fatal: The current branch master has no upstream branch. To push the current 
>   branch and set the remote as upstream, use
>   git push --set-upstream work master

also dind't work.

> Repository not found

I've tried also `git push -u rep_1` and got the same errors. I have no ideas what should I do.

Comment: Maybe 1 isn't really a good name for a repository reference? Also it seems you're mixing things. 1 is a folder, a repo reference, or a branch? You need to `git remote add myRepo ...; git push myRepo master`.

Comment: Did you try deleting the .git folder and starting over? Also make sure to switch to correct branch with git checkout branch_name

Comment: I think your steps are quite wrong and mixed up as Ondra has suggested. Can you tell what is your actual requirement? what do you want to happen in your question and we can suggest what steps need to be followed.

Answer (score 0):

> In rep_1 there are 5 folders (1,2,...,5), and there is index.html in each. I made new folder 'work' and i git clone  my forked repo. In folder 1/index.html I used git init and git add . and git commit -m to make some changes.

Here you are saying that you have cloned a repo. Later you are initializing a new repository with git init. So, when you do that this repository is totally different from the repo you cloned. Therefore, you will not be able to push to the existing repository (I am assuming the remote that you are adding is for the repository you cloned from.)

Having, said that if you can tell what your requirement is , I can suggest what steps need to be followed.

Answer (score 0):

Basically，git will search repository information (usually .git) from current folder to upper folder until a .git was found.

For your question, the local repository you created in folder 1 will be used. So you can not push to remote by this local information.

It is not recommended to create new repository in the work directory of the other repository.

Answer (score 0):

You can't clone the same repo in the subfolder. The reason why you can’t push as below:

1. You cloned you rep_1 in folder `/work`, so your local repo in the directory `/work/rep_1`
2. In folder `/work/rep_1/1`, you used `git init` to create a new local repo and made some changes in it
3. And then you add the remote repo rep_1 and want to push things in folder `/work/rep_1/1`. But please remember, `/work/rep_1/1` is the subfolder of your local repo in step1, you also have folders /2, /3, /4, /5.
4. There is an interesting thing is that if you use `git pull --allow-unrelated-histories`, and then go to directory `/work/rep_1` use `git status`, you will find what you changed in `/work/rep_1/1` all show here
5. So you use `git push 1`, it really checks the status in `/work/rep_1` and compare the SHA-1 of HEAD with the remote
6. If you need to push changes, you can do it in `/work/rep_1` directly

Answer (score 0):

You just need to enter the repository folder "rep_1" you've cloned and then run

```
git add *
git commit -m "x"
git push
```

to push all the changes you made in the 5 folders to remote repository.